# Use c# functions inside XPath expressions

Tags: c#, xpath

Is it possible to add/use custom  functions inside .Net XPath evaluator? For example, I'd like to do a search with regex, which xPath 1.0 does not support. Can I add something similar to

```
bool RegexSearch(string regex, string text)
```

and register it with something similar to

```
xPathNavigator.RegisterFunction("regex-search",RegexSearch);
```

so I can use it inside my xPath queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to inherit from `System.Xml.Xsl.XsltContext`. Please check this link for details of the implementation.

[Using ms: xpath functions inside XPathExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320505/using-ms-xpath-functions-inside-xpathexpression)

MSDN - [Adding Custom Functions to XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950806.aspx)

Microsoft KB Article, the original link on MS is [dead](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/Q324462). But I manage to find an alternate - 
[HOW TO: Implement and Use Custom Extension Functions When You Execute XPath Queries in Visual C# .NET.](http://www.c-bit.org/Q/324899/EN-US/)

Comment: Good Link to MSDN - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms950806(v=msdn.10)#comparison-of-two-strings