# Xml content did not recognized by template

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have xml with a tag which contains an attribute with a **html** content in it. I need to convert this **html** to **xsl-fo** . Here is my **xslt** code:

```
  <xsl:template match ="rtf">
    <fo:block-container>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name ="ConvertHtmlToXslfo">
          <xsl:with-param name ="content">
            <xsl:value-of select ="@rtfAsHtml" disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
          </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="ConvertHtmlToXslfo">
    <xsl:param name ="content"></xsl:param>
    <fo:block-container>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($content)"/> <!--here is the problem-->

    </fo:block-container>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="div">
    <fo:block-container>
        <!--more code here-->
    </fo:block-container>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="p">
    <fo:block>
        <!--more code here-->
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="span">
    <fo:inline>
        <!--more code here-->
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>
```

But there is a problem, when in call apply-templates on this **html** content. the relevant templates doesn't recognize it.

Here is the xml Tag with **Html** attribute in it:

```
<rtf rtfAsHtml="&lt;div &gt;&lt;p &gt;&lt;span&gt;Hi!&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"/>
```

Any idea how to convert this Html tag to xsl-fo ?

thank you!

Comment: does your input file have any namespace declarations? Also, if you are able to match "rtf" as the document node, it seems to me that your input is RTF rather than HTML.

Comment: @MathiasMüller. No, my input haven't any namespaces. And, my input is a xml tag that contains html that converted from rtf. but it is html.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your xml/html content is escaped. You try to apply disable-output-escaping, but that only works upon writing to output file or stream. So, you are effectively just submitting the unescaped attribute contents against your templates, which doesn't do much indeed.

Not sure what kind of XSLT parser you are using, but if you use Saxon, you could try to apply saxon:parse:

http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/parse.html

This does require the contents of the attribute to be well-formed. If not, you could try:

http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/parse-html.html

HTH!

Comment: Thanks. you are right. but i'm using Microsoft XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: @jacob There doesn't seem to be an equivalent for those parse functions in .Net unfortunately. You can revert to Saxon.Net of course. Other alternative would be to create your own XPath extension function. I found this on stackoverflow showing examples how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320505/using-ms-xpath-functions-inside-xpathexpression

Comment: It might be possible to use something similar to this answer, where a "parser for escaped XML" is implemented in XSLT: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20150995/407651.