# XPath Equivalent of "match any"

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XPath I'm using on a SOAP message:

```
//*[contains('RedID,GreenID,BlueID',local-name())]
```

Using an XPathNavigator it works perfectly, except if the SOAP body contains something like this:

```
<s:Body>
<RunStuff xmlns="http://serve.com/2013/11">
    <arg>5</arg>
    <data xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Injection.Test" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <b:ID>5</b:ID>
        <b:BlueID>600d2517-7126-4fcf-8155-c4a50ab3cc10</b:BlueID>
        <b:account>0</b:account>
    </data>
</RunStuff>
</s:Body>
```

The XPath will match the `ID` element when instead it was the `BlueID` I was trying to capture.  I can simply collect all the results and filter out the bad matches, but I'd like to know if there is a more clever XPath statement that would not accidentally match the `ID` field, or accidently match a field called `Blue`, etcetera.

The MSDN documentation says that [XPathNavigator supports XPath 1.0 and 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but when I try this...

```
//*[local-name()=('RedID','BludID')]
```

...I get a bad token error.  I got that syntax from [this link](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.xml/2006-08/msg00019.html).  So then I tried this...

```
//*[exists(index-of(('RedID','BlueID'), 'RedID) )]
```

This also gives me a bad token error.  I also tried another variant that gave me an error saying I must load an XsltContext.  That error led me to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320505/using-ms-xpath-functions-inside-xpathexpression).  The answer from user "ertan" involved writing my own C# function, which is more involved than I intended.  I'm looking for something simpler - something directly supported by XPath "as is".

I will resort to constructing a bunch of `or` statements if I must...

```
//*[local-name()="RedID" OR local-name()="BludID"]
```

But I'd still like to know if there is any easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty much stuck with using `contains()` here because you're working with a list of string values and not a list of nodes, but you can do this to prevent any partial matches:

```
//*[contains('|RedID|GreenID|BlueID|', concat('|', local-name(), '|'))]
```

The MSDN documentation doesn't say that `XPathNavigator` supports XPath 2.0 expressions. What it says is:

> > The XPathNavigator class in the System.Xml.XPath namespace is an abstract class which **defines a cursor model for navigating and editing XML information items as instances of the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model**.

I'm fairly sure that there is nothing built into .NET that supports XPath 2.0.